# Convert PowerShell Command to Script

Tags: powershell

The PowerShell command below turns off the screen when run from a batch file (or command prompt). I would prefer to run this as a PowerShell script.

> [Turn Off Screen - TechNet Script Center](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Turn-off-screen-4d173e0a)
>
> `powershell (Add-Type '[DllImport(\"user32.dll\")]^public static
>   extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);'
>   -Name a
>   -Pas)::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)`

I looked at [Add-Type - Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/add-type?view=powershell-6), but I could not get the parameters correct.

What is the equivalent PowerShell script for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Add-Type -MemberDefinition @"
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern int SendMessage(int hWnd, int hMsg, int wParam, int lParam);
"@  -Name "Win32SendMessage" -Namespace "Win32Functions"

[Win32Functions.Win32SendMessage]::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,2)
```

Comment: `[Win32Functions.Win32SendMessage]::SendMessage(-1,0x0112,0xF170,-1)` to turn monitor on.